# Set different folders in different alias in the same server

Tags: windows, server, alias, directory

In my **windows server 2012** I have setting two alias :

1. http://kpi.xxx.yyy
2. http://kpc.xxx.yyy

Now I need associate the alias on different folders on **inetpub/wwwroot** in **IIS**

1. http://kpi.xxx.yyy >>> *folder KPI*;
2. http://kpc.xxx.yyy >>> *folder KPC*.

I have find in Google without success.

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this **Default.asp** in your directory **inetpub/wwwroot** :

```
<% 
Dim strProtocol
Dim strDomain
Dim strFullUrl

If lcase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) = "on" Then 
    strProtocol = "https" 
Else
    strProtocol = "http" 
End If

strDomain= Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

strFullUrl = strProtocol & "://" & strDomain & "/"

If strFullUrl = "http://kpi.xxx.yyy/" then
   Response.Redirect("http://kpi.xxx.yyy/folder KPI/")
ElseIf strFullUrl = "http://kpc.xxx.yyy/" then
   Response.Redirect("http://kpc.xxx.yyy/folder KPC/")
End If

%>
```